# How can I prevent unauthorized changes to VMs in GCP and ensure all modifications are made through IaC?

Tags: security, terraform, infrastructure-as-code

I want to ensure that all modifications made to VMs in GCP are done through Infrastructure as Code (IaC) and reviewed before implementation. Additionally, I want to prevent any unauthorized modifications made by users who can SSH into the VMs.

Can anyone suggest a method or tool that can help me achieve this objective? Ideally, I'd like to be alerted if any unauthorized modifications are made to a VM, and have the ability to automatically revert the VM to its previous state.

For example, I have a VM that has `A`,`B`,and `C`. Then suddenly there is a user who ssh into this VM and install `D`. Is it possible to:

- Detect this unauthorized changes
- Automatically revert so that there is no `D`
- Initiation of the VM will be through IaC and all of `A`, `B`, and `C` are determined in IaC such as in terraform

Another example is that, I have a VM, and suddenly there is an attacker that succesfully ssh into this VM and wipe and change everything inside. What can we do so that when the attacker do any of that action, it can be properly logged and it can alert the action to me in a realtime. Even if the attacker can open some config file and change some values inside it, I can know the difference (like git)

Thank you for any guidance or advice you can provide!